# Empty topology in apache Ignite in Java

Tags: java, ignite

I am starting apache Ignite when my Jboss started successfully. Please find below code -

Ignition.start(getConfiguration());

```
public static IgniteConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
    TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();

    List<String> address = new ArrayList<>();
    address.add("X.X.X.X:47500..47509");
    ipFinder.setAddresses(address);

    discoSpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);
    return cfg;
  }
```

The Ignite cluster started successfully and below is the log details -

22:32:22,839 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]    __________  ________________
22:32:22,846 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]   /  */* / |/ /  */*  __/ __/
22:32:22,866 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / */
22:32:22,873 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] /*/___/*/|*/***/ /*/ /_**/
22:32:22,879 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]
22:32:22,884 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] ver. 2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270
22:32:22,889 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
22:32:22,893 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]
22:32:22,897 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
22:32:22,902 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]
22:32:22,906 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] Quiet mode.
22:32:22,930 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]   ^-- Logging by 'Log4JLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
22:32:22,936 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
22:32:22,941 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22]
22:32:22,949 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
22:32:22,953 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:22] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_92-b14 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14
22:32:23,061 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:23] Configured plugins:
22:32:23,070 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:23]   ^-- None
22:32:23,076 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:23]
22:32:23,196 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:23] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
22:32:23,255 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:23] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
22:32:25,176 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
22:32:25,181 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
22:32:25,185 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
22:32:25,190 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
22:32:25,196 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
22:32:25,200 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
22:32:25,206 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]
22:32:25,211 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
22:32:25,216 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]
22:32:25,220 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] Ignite node started OK (id=9ed81825)
22:32:25,227 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] Topology snapshot [**ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, offheap=3.2GB, heap=1.0GB**]
22:32:25,232 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25] Data Regions Configured:
22:32:25,238 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) [22:32:25]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=3.2 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]

But when I am starting visor, its and connect it, I am getting empty topology.

visor> top
Empty topology.
visor>

Please help whats wrong here .

**Note** - As I am not using any xml file for IgniteConfiguration ( doing it through Java API), then which xml file I should select while starting Visor ?

Comment: I am almost certain that you forgot to include the same discovery configuration into Visor startup. Can you please specify the same IpFinder configuration there? You will have to provide it via XML.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that you need to create an XML file for Visor configuration that matches the same IP Finder as specified in your code.

Comment: Thanks. This helped-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visor configuration and Ignite startup configuration should be same for Visor to communicate and display the statistics.

Thank you very much **Dmitriy** for your input